# Android studio gradle variants and stack traces

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

When I analyze a stack trace in Android Studio it always pulls from the main build variant version of a given code file.  For example:

```
/main/test.java <-- 
/pro/test.java
```

It will always reference the file in main even if I switch my variant.  Is there something I'm missing regarding associating the current view with a variant?

Comment: Have you changed your flavour in the (usually bottom-left) tab called variants? If not, you can pull it up from the popup menu on the bottom left of AS.

Comment: There it is.  It used to be in the upper right.  I checked the popup but somehow missed it (it was there as well).  Thanks, add the answer if you like.

Comment: Actually the studio still pulls the main version of code even when I switch to the pro variant.

Comment: Main is pulled for all versions as it is the common classes, move your code to one of the flavour's folders.

Comment: I'm describing a simplified case, but trust me in that I've been using the flavors successfully from the day the studio was released in alpha.  I moved and couldn't develop for six months and a lot has changed.  The flavors are intact, in fact I just released three flavors without issue.  However responding to crash reports is a nightmare given that choosing a variant does not cause the code to link properly.  This used to work, so I'm familiar with the process (as I last recall when I selected the variant in the upper-right corner).  It, unfortunately, does not work now.